# Elixir how to combine $(document).ready(function(){}

Tags: javascript, compilation, laravel-5, gulp

I'm using **Laravel 5.1**, and **Elixir/Gulp** to combine multiple javascript files. I'm noticing that when combining files, it's a literal combination, and does not 'combine' `$(document).ready(function(){}` blocks.

gulpfile.js:

```
mix.scripts([
  'file1.js',
  'file2.js'
], 'public/js/files.js');
```

file1.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // do something 1
});
```

file2.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // do something 2
});
```

Final output files.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            // do something 1
    });
$(document).ready(function(){
            // do something 2
    });
```

My intended output is to combine the blocks to get:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            // do something 1
            // do something 2
    });
```

Is this possible with Elixir, or am I needing to use another compilation tool?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple. Combining two lexical scopes can have side effects.

Consider:

```
function func1() {
    x = 1;
};
function func2() {
    var x = 2;
};

func1();
func2();
alert(typeof x);  // "number"
```

Now combine them:

```
function func1and2() {
    x = 1;
    var x = 2;
};

func1and2();
alert(typeof x);  // "undefined"
```

This has to do with how javascript "var" objects become visible everywhere in their function, even before they're declared.

Going forward, you have the "let" keyword which finally gives javascript lexically scoped identifiers. If your two ready() functions both used a "let" variable with the same name, the result of just combining them would be a SyntaxError.